# Finding the Size of Set with Certain Conditions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, problem-solving

For any set $A$, let $T(A)$ be the set consisting of all sets $S \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ that satisfy the following conditions:

- (i) $\emptyset \in S$
- (ii) $A \in S$
- (iii) $\forall X, Y \in S, (X \cup Y) \in S$
- (iv) $\forall X, Y \in S, (X \cap Y) \in S$

What are the number of elements of the set $\{S \in T(\{1, 2, 3\}) : |S| \geqslant 5\}$?

I'm not sure how to go about this. Handling these extra conditions makes finding the size of tis set difficult for me.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Vsotvep So far I have written a programming solution to the problem and brute forced the number of sets, but I have no idea how to write a mathematical solution.

Comment: Programming is nice to find a solution, but I bet this problem has been given to you to test your understanding of the problem statement (and not programming skills). How about starting out like this: since $A$ has $3$ elements, $\mathcal P(A)$ has $2^3=8$ elements (why is this $2^{|A|}$?). Now, what happens when we remove one of those elements and create a $7$ element subset of $\mathcal P(A)$. Does that still satisfy the conditions? What if we remove two? Does it matter which elements we remove?